# preg_match is not finding my words

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

Hi I did a form in the order to find words in my files with preg_match but this function is not finding all words.

For example : I have 5 documents on my server (pdf, doc and txt). I try to find the word "php" and I have 2 results but this word appears at least 30 times in my documents. Why I have only 2 results ?

An another error : line numbers are not always correct.

Thanks for your help!

My code :

```
    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
        $file=$donnees['filepath'];
        $fname=$donnees['filename'];
        $path="C:/xampp/htdocs/test".$file;
        $lines = file($path);
        foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        if (preg_match_all('|\b' . preg_quote($mot) . '\b|i', $line)) {
            echo "<center>Word ".$word." find at line ".($line_num+1)." in the file ".$fname."</center>";
            }

}

}
```

Comment: Is the word 'php' occurring multiple times on the same line? Or is it on 30 different lines?

Comment: It's on 30 different lines. And sometimes I have no result but the word appears many times in several files.

Comment: Your code assumes that PDF and Word files are plain text files and use single-byte encodings.

Comment: What it means ? I think that the research is working with txt files but there are many bugs whith PDF and DOC files. How could I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Those are binary files, not text.  Any occurrence of those characters are just a coincidence.

Comment: So how can I resolve the problem ?

Comment: I'm put an analogy: image you're looking for `php` in an HTML document and you have this: `<span class="first-letter">p</span>hp`.

Comment: Do you know a solution to resolve this problem ?

Comment: You would have to translate all of the DOC and PDF files to text files (or the equivalent) to be able to manipulate the content therein. Then, you would do your search on the text versions of the files. You can see many examples of the PDF2TXT version on the PHP site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php (though I doubt any of them works 100% of the time).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your link, I think it will be useful!